# ASP.NET Charting - Dynamic chart wrongly built

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to create a chart from the following DataTable:
[image: DataTable1][image: DataTable2]

In my aspx page, I have a simple chart, the code is the following:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chartTipo1" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" Palette="Pastel" TextAntiAliasingQuality="High" Width="1400px" Height="500px" Visible="false">
    <Series></Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisX IsStartedFromZero="True" LineColor="LightGray" LabelAutoFitStyle="LabelsAngleStep30" IsLabelAutoFit="true">
                <MajorGrid LineColor="White" />
            </AxisX>
            <AxisY LineColor="LightGray">
                <MajorGrid LineColor="LightGray" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend BorderWidth="1"></asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```

And the code-behind:

```
//first add your series
foreach (DataRow row in dtTipos.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new string[] { "Type"}).Rows)
{
    Series series = new Series();
    series.Name = (string)row["Type"];
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
    chartTipo1.Series.Add(series);
}

// then add your points;
foreach (DataRow row in dtTipos.Rows)
    chartTipo1.Series[(string)row["Type"]].Points.AddXY(row["Location"], new object[] { row["Total"] });

double pInicial = 0.5;
for (int i = 0; i < listaLocais.Count; i++)
{
    chartTipo1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(pInicial, pInicial + 1, listaLocais[i]); 
    chartTipo1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
    pInicial = pInicial + 1;
}
```

I create a series for each different Type and then add the points. After this I add a label for each column (I should be having 6 different columns, from 6 different locations).

The resulting chart is the following:
[image]

As you can see, the chart is wrongly built, since the Location 'Azeitão' only has one type associated, not more as displayed in the chart.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That means that you are building your series in a wrong way....first build your locations axis and then add the clients for that location only(you should check that the client belongs to that location before adding it to the serie)

Comment: So my series should be the types or the locations?

Comment: If a particular `Location` does not have a particular `Type`, you will have to add that Location-Type pair with a `Total` value of 0(zero). Then it will work the way you expect. For this particular type of stacked column chart, you cannot simply dump your data table on it with "missing" pieces of data. The chart itself is not "smart" enough to figure it all out for you. You have to do the work on your data and feed it with structure and consistency to the chart.

Comment: It fixed my problem @jstreet

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment, thanks @jstreet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @jstreet 's help I was able to fix my problem.

What I did: 

I created a list with all the different locations, and a list with all the different types. Then, for each one of my rows in the DataTable, I searched for a row with this location and this type, using

```
DataRow[] lRow = dtTipos.Select("LOCATION= '" + l + "' AND TYPE= '" + t + "'");
```

Then, if I had found a row, I would add a Point to the series with the correspondent value, else I would add a Point with value 0 to the column so I could create an empty column for each type that didn't exist for each location.

Problem solved.